# How to create azure vm instance on a dual boot linux machine? Is the procedure same as we do it on a virtual machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, azure, virtual-machines

I want to create an azure vm instance anc access it through ssh. But I have a dual booted linux machine. So can I do the same on a dual booted machine or I need specifically a virtual machine to create an azure vm instance?

Answer (score 2):

You may create Azure VMs with anything that speaks the API, including [Azure CLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-cli-complete) or various automation tools. You may access the VM over any SSH client, including [OpenSSH](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-ssh-keys-detailed) or PuTTY. Azure docs have how to guides for Linux, macOS, or Windows (other platforms are possible).

Whether you use a workstation, developer environment, or bastion host to do this, and on which OS, is entirely your preference.

Comment: Okay, I will try to do this. Thanks for the answer.